# Virtualization On Linux Server

Tags: vmware, virtualization

In my office we've just purchased two new servers, which will be Ubuntu Linux servers, and we are going to be completely virtualizing our environment. I have a bootable USB with ESXi 5 on it, does anyone have any tips on how to get the virtual machines installed on a Linux machine? This is something that I've never done before!

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Can you tell us what you have tried and/or researched? Please [edit your question](http://askubuntu.com/posts/388732/edit) and add the information. There are many possibilities how to virtualize a Linux installation. To narrow down the possibilities you should give us something to work with. I.e. why do you want to virtualize? How is the server going to be used?

Answer (score 3):

My personal advice (as a professional systems administrator with a great deal of experience with virtualisation - both Ubuntu and VMware-based) is that if you even need to ask this question, you will need to hire consultants/experts to implement what you need.

There's a number of reasons for this, but first and foremost is the quality of the implementation. If this is the first time you've used virtualisation, Ubuntu or VMware (you didn't specify which), can you honestly guarantee that everything will be set up exactly right, when these servers are going to be used in a business environment? Can you be counted on to fix things when they go wrong and know enough about the set-up to troubleshoot?

A few explanatory points:

- Ubuntu and VMware ESXi (aka vSphere) are **both** operating systems - you can use one *or* the other as your server's base operating system.
- VMware ESXi is a **hypervisor** - a special type of operating system which means it can easily run other systems as virtual machines. You can use ESXi to run Ubuntu virtual machines, but **not** the other way around.
- If you already have virtual machines that you were running on VMware and now you want to run on Ubuntu, ask yourself *Why?*